# Export model to minecraft json format?

Tags: export

My friend is paying me a good ammount of money to make some weapons for a minecraft game. I am good with blender and he said he needs minecraft .json files, which you cannot export with blender. Is there a way to make the model minecraft compatible?

[image]

Have tried using some old .json addon exporters but they are not working, as minecraft has a different .json type.

Comment: try with threejs addon for blender

Comment: A few seconds of googling found a [minecraft-specific exporter here](https://github.com/freundTech/blender2minecraft). I know this is an old question, but maybe it'll be helpful to someone.